# Flutter: how to make ios scroll to top gesture for bidirectional custom view with center key?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, scroll

I'm doing something like a news feed and I'm using CustomScrollView with two slivers (one for initially loaded news and one for new news that should not shift elements when loaded).

Example:

```
return CustomScrollView(
  center: centerKey,
  slivers: [
    renderOneList(newItems),
    renderOneList(oldItems, centerKey),
  ],
);
```

Everything works as it should. I use UniqueKey to define the first element where the initial reading starts. Once every X seconds, I load new items and put them into an array of newItems. They are added to the top and the user can scroll to the top.

However, when clicking on the status bar in iOS Primary Scroll Controller scrolls to position 0 (which in my case is the boundary of new news and old news). This is correct from Flutter's point of view, but it's not the behavior I would like to achieve. Any ideas on how to scroll to the top?

What I think about it:

1. It is possible to move records from oldItems to newItems when scrolling up, but that would cause a lot of redraws and I probably wouldn't be able to guess the timing of the swap.
2. While tapping on the status bar, scroll up X pixels in Y milliseconds. Doesn't seem like a great option either.

I ended up with a dead end, but I'm sure the community has solved such a basic problem before. Hope for some help.

Comment: Did you try to wrap  your customScrollVew with ``PrimaryScrollController`` widget and add ``renderOneList`` scroll controller to ``PrimaryScrollController`` widget

Comment: @ĐứcThànhLê, for what?

Comment: To specify which is a primary controller in your view, cause your view have multiple list with different scroll controller,

Comment: @ĐứcThànhLê, my controller is installed correctly. The question is how to scroll to the beginning instead of the middle. Also I can't put a controller for renderOneList as it is a sliver that is inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using [`Scrollable.ensureVisible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html).

I don't know how `renderOneList` is implemented so let's assume it's a `SliverList` on which you optionally set the `key` (used for `centerKey`).

If that's the case, then you can simply set a global key on the first sliver too and use this key with `ensureVisible`.

Here's a working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollToTopExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollToTopExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: scrollToTop,
              child: Text('Scroll to top example'),
            ),
          ),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            center: GlobalObjectKey('center-key'),
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                key: GlobalObjectKey('top-key'),
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item -${index + 1}'),
                  ),
                  childCount: 100,
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                key: GlobalObjectKey('center-key'),
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
                  ),
                  childCount: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // Status bar tap override
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
          child: GestureDetector(
            excludeFromSemantics: true,
            onTap: onStatusBarTap,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void scrollToTop() {
    final key = GlobalObjectKey('top-key');
    final context = key.currentContext;

    if (context == null) {
      return;
    }

    Scrollable.ensureVisible(
      context,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      alignment: 0.0,
      alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit,
    );
  }

  void onStatusBarTap() {
    print('onStatusBarTap');
    scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

The important part here is the `alignment: 0` parameter together with `alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit` which ensures that the top of the target element is aligned with the top of the scrollable container.

If you need more fine-grained control of the scroll position (eg. scroll to a certain item) you will need to set a key on the item's widget and make sure the widget is in the tree. For this reason, I believe using `Scrollable.ensureVisible` will not work to scroll to a certain item when the list is built dynamically using `ListView.builder`, `SliverList.builder` (or `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`).

Comment: Thanks, dude! I've been looking for this method for a long time now. This works like a charm. Unfortunately, this method doesn't lie on the surface and all the customizations are not obvious at all. Thanks again, this has helped me a lot!

Comment: maybe you know, how can I listen for ios status bar tap for call this function?

Comment: @AlexIvashkin sure, it can be done by adding a gesture detector over the status bar area. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: I see that you updated and now tap is recognized by the app bar, however I was asking about the status bar on iOS (the very top where the current time is displayed).

Comment: I left the `onTap` on the `AppBar` as it was but I nested the `Scaffold` in a `Stack` and added a `Positioned` which should cover the status bar area. Now the `scrollToTop` should be triggered both by tap on title and on the status bar. Please give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

```dart
// try this one

ScrollController sc = ScrollController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  sc.addListener(() {
    if (sc.offset <= 0) {
      // Implement your custom scrolling logic here
    }
  });
}

// ...

return CustomScrollView(
  controller: sc,
  slivers: [
    renderOneList(newItems),
    renderOneList(oldItems),
  ],
);
```

Comment: So the question is exactly how to calculate that negative offset to scroll up by.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).